# ScrollView animated

Tags: animation, while-loop, scrollview, move

(sorry for my English)

I'm looking for an animation to scrollview when an item (textview in this case) gets out of visibility. I would like put it an animation like fade_out when te item reach up or down of the scrollview, or/and when it becomes visible.

It's that posible? Any tips to do it? I tried to search in Google, but nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One good way is to overlay a view with an alpha gradient going from 0 to 1. The content of your scroll view, including the text view, will then just seem to fade out towards the edges.